# How to make multiple circle in google map flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, flutter-dependencies

I have multiple locations on different radius, and i want to draw circles according to radius values. if you see in the picture two circle is showing according to its radius value

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really easy by using this code:

```
    Set<Circle> mCircle = Set.from([
    Circle(
        circleId: CircleId(id1),
        center: LatLng(lat, lng),
        radius: 500,
    ),
Circle(
        circleId: CircleId(id2),
        center: LatLng(lat2, lng2),
        radius: 500,
    )

]);
    
    GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: initialMapLocation,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        onCameraMove: null,
        circles: mCircle,
      );
```

Comment: How can we insert text into the circle?